# C# yield return using same reference

Tags: c#, yield-return

I have a problem with my iterator in C# which I can't seem to resolve. Here are the two relevant methods (simplified for the purposes of the question):

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<T> Iterator()
{
    // Code here omitted for brevity

    foreach(object row in compiler.ResultsIterator())
    {
        Model obj;

        object[] row_array = new object[fields_length];
        // Logic to set row_array values omitted for brevity
        obj = _model.Clone(); // Does a MemberwiseClone
        obj.SetFieldValues(row_array);
        yield return (T)(obj as object);
    }
}

private void FillCache()
{
    IEnumerator<T> _iter = Iterator().GetEnumerator();
    while(_iter.MoveNext())
    {
        ResultCache.Add(_iter.Current);
    }
}
```

The issue is that on the first iteration in FillCache() ResultCache contains an object, let's call it 'Object 1' but on the second iteration it contains 'Object 2' twice. Clearly the problem is that the variable 'obj' is passed by reference and is not being created new even though it is declared inside the foreach loop.

So my question is how can I create a new 'obj' reference each time?

Comment: That code cannot possibly compile, you're returning `obj` after it has gone out of scope. Please provide a minimum, *verifiable* and complete example.

Comment: You probably too simply your example because: you declare `Model obj;` inside foreach, and return the object outside.

Comment: @dcastro The code does compile and works as described.

Comment: The conversion to `object` might be incompatible with `T`.

Comment: I second dcastro; the scope of `obj` is limited to the body of the foreach statement.

Comment: This code does not compile

Comment: @Codor That is not the problem. I always get a Model back.

Comment: @RobinElvin: Have you actually pasted the code you supplied into VS? It does not compile.

Comment: @RobinElvin Then there's only one possible explanation: you have a field named `obj`, and the local variable `obj` shadows the field. If that is so, returning the *field* `obj` would explain why you get the same reference

Comment: Why doesn't it compile?

Comment: @RobinElvin Just try it yourself. Start a new project and paste the code above into it. The "obj" variable is out of scope when you try to yield it in your example above.

Comment: @RobinElvin Because the `obj` variable is declared inside the loop, and is therefore inaccessible outside the loop. See this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4egAN4

Comment: Code is invalid. Impossible to help because meaning and problem are unclear. Closing.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I see what you are all saying now. I've put the yield in the right place. It was a cut and paste error.

Comment: What does the `Clone` method in the question look like?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You hit the nail on the head :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I feel bad about misleading with the yield problem but the issue is a question of references. It turns out the real problem is the MemberwiseClone because this is only a shallow copy so all the deep member references are the same.

Therefore the answer is that the Clone() method should perform a deep copy.

Comment: This is why posting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is so important. We couldn't run your code ourselves, so we had to trust your assumptions. Namely, the assumption that the cache contained the same object twice. If we could run the code ourselves, we could draw our own conclusions and see where you went wrong. Anyhow, I'm glad you got your problem sorted :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're able to compile that code and we aren't, there's only one possible explanation: you have a field named `obj`, and the local variable `obj` shadows the field.

If that is so, returning the *field* `obj` would explain why you get the same reference on every iteration

Comment: Nope, there is no other obj. In fact I renamed the variable to make sure and reran with that same result.

Comment: @RobinElvin Select the `obj` in `yield return (T)(obj as object);` and press `F12`. Visual studio will take you to place where `obj` is declared.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It takes me to the declaration in the foreach

Comment: @RobinElvin Then the code you shown and what you have are not equivalent. If not original code, at least post the equivalent one.